# How do I show only 4 days of the week instead of 7?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I've created a Date column and used the calendar function to list a date range. Here's the DAX formula I used:

```
Data = Calendar( Date(2018, 4, 1), Date(2021,4,30))
```

However, my goal now is to ONLY show 4 days of the week within the specified date range more specifically Sunday, Monday, Wednesday and Thursday. How do I achieve this result?

Any guidance will be appreciated.
Thank you.

I tried using the filter function but need further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your DAX for a calculated table:

```
Data = 
FILTER(
    Calendar( Date(2018, 4, 1), Date(2021, 4, 30)),
    WEEKDAY([Date]) < 3 || WEEKDAY([Date]) = 4 || WEEKDAY([Date]) = 5
)
```